# How to Display a pdf, rft, doc, txt on a overlay?

Tags: files, modal-dialogs

I collect user resumes by using a file field. That field is been display it on view and when you click on it it would download the resume file (either pdf, rft, doc, txt). I would like to open that document a overlay instead of downloading the document.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You chekced [pdf](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf) or [pdf_reader](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf_reader) modules? in order to display it on an overlay open its link in [lightbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightbox2)